# avoid user from accessing web page using old session/other user session

Tags: session, authentication

ive tried to destroy current user session after 30 minutes. it works fine.
the problem is

1) when other user open a link of  the web page in new tab they manage to access the page without going tru login process.

Ive tried to follow this tutorial

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php14p3.html

```
<?PHP

session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header ("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

but its not working. because old session has not been destroyed yet (less than 30 minutes)..

what should i do??

Comment: "when other user open a link of the web page in new tab" it sounds like you are letting two users browse using the same browser?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the login session of a user is stored in a single cookie per website which is shared in all windows and tabs of a single browser. Clearing the cookies in your browser would require you to login again because when you next access the remote website (your PHP site) you would not be passing the cookie with the old session id anymore.

This presents a problem for you when two people are using the same browser because that cookie for your website is the same for both people.

One option for you is to provide a manual 'logout' button on your PHP site which would destroy the session before the 30 minute timeout occurs. However, there's no guarantee a user will click this button when they are done.

From the PHP docs on [session id passing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php):

> There are two methods to propagate a session id:
>
> - Cookies
> - URL parameter
>
> The session module supports both methods. Cookies are optimal, but
>   because they are not always available, we also provide an alternative
>   way. The second method embeds the session id directly into URLs.

This shows there is another option for you where you enable the run-time option `session.use_trans_sid` and the session id gets embedded in every url instead of being stored in a cookie. With this you would get something like the `mysession=123` value at the end of the following url: `www.example.com/home.php?mysession=123`

So if user 1 visits www.example.com and performs a login then every link will have `mysession=123` at the end of it for as long as their session is active.

Then user 2 browses to www.example.com in a new tab and they are asked to login again because there was no `mysession=###` value in the url they typed in. After logging in on this tab, every link will have a new value for mysession like `www.example.com/home.php?mysession=345`

**Warning:** There's a reason most sites prefer to use cookies as you can see in this note about the [use-trans-sid setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) in the PHP documentation.

> URL based session management has additional security risks compared to
>   cookie based session management. Users may send a URL that contains an
>   active session ID to their friends by email or users may save a URL
>   that contains a session ID to their bookmarks and access your site
>   with the same session ID always, for example.

Comment: Clearly explained. It seems like the only option left is by using url. cant the trans-sid setting generate randomly? @nvuono

Comment: If you wanted to regenerate the users session id every time you could use the `session_regenerate_id(true)` which will create a new session and copy the contents of the old one over to the new one then destroying the previous session. This however will not remove all of the security risks with URL session passing yet session security in general.